# Does Bootstrap work with epubs?

Tags: epub

Can Bootstrap be used in an epub? If so, can anyone point me to a good reference or tutorial?

I tried Googling for information, but I most get pages describing epubs that feature Bootstrap as their topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your question is:  can bootstrap be used to generate code for an epub file?

I don't really know anything about bootstrap, but I know that there is a blitz framework which uses  the  [less preprocessor](https://github.com/FriendsOfEpub/Blitz) to generate responsive epub css.

You might find interesting [the two tutorials](https://medium.com/@jiminypan/blitzintrotutorial-270da9f853c0) and [here](https://medium.com/@jiminypan/a-css-api-for-ebooks-df469a347c0c) by the guy who started this framework

(I have not tried it out myself, but like the idea of it).